# Random Number Generator that allows me to access the "seed" whenever I want

Tags: node.js, npm, random, cryptography, random-seed

I am using NodeJs and need a cryptographically secure random number generator. I have tried researching and finding various ways to generate these secure numbers, and I have been using the npm module 'secure-random' but now I have a new requirement that I must be able to print out what seed was used everytime I print out a random number. I am unsure how to do that with the current module and was hoping someone could either direct me to a different library to use as I've searched for hours, or guide me on actually making a function myself. Currently I have a function that looks like:

```
function roll(min,max){
var data = secureRandom.randomUint8Array(1);
data = data[0]/(Math.pow(2,8)-1)
data = Math.floor(data * (max - min + 1) + min);
return data
}
```

But now I need a function that creates a secure random number and allows me to return the seed as well for every iteration of the function.

Thank you for the help

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/386992). What exactly are you doing that you have those requirements?

Comment: Sorry, after reading what an XY problem is I see that I could have phrased it better. Basically I am asking are there any npm libraries or tools for nodejs that allow me to generate secure random numbers and know the seed that was used for generating them. And I am doing this for a discord bot that I am making, it uses random numbers for giving out prices but I want the seeds present to ensure fairness to everyone.

Comment: How would having the seed ensure fairness?

Comment: If they know the seed for their role they can test it with the algorithm and see if their output was the same. If not they know its been rigged

Comment: Are you planning to use a cryptographic commitment too? If not, then your idea won't help. Either you tell them the seed at the beginning, and they can cheat by predicting what will come next, or you tell them the seed at the end, and you can cheat by brute-forcing a seed that works for the outputs you hand-picked.

Comment: Hmm, I honestly am not sure. Is there a way to truly prove that the number generated is "random" and wasn't brute forced?

Comment: The important thing isn't whether the value is random or not. The important thing is that you can prove you picked it at the beginning, even though you don't show them until the end, and that's exactly what cryptographic commitments do.

Comment: Oh interesting didn't know that. So since I am using this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/secure-random, that should be fine correct? I would just need to prove that it was picked at the beginning?

Comment: I would warn you that using the word "just" is often not applicable for cryptography. Don't be fooled by simple words, they may hide complex algorithms.

Comment: The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commitment_scheme) is a decent place to start.